# Have any notable mathematical constants been found which are known to be rational?

Tags: soft-question

Has anyone else thought about this? I've browsed the Wikipedia for mathematical constants and only things I saw that were definitely rational AFAIK were 0, 1, 2, and 1/2, which don't really count.

I think 777480/8288641 counts also. Fermat's/ Euler's Diophantine problem.

Are there any questions which have been asked where a rational answer is expected to be the answer?

Seeking tags also because I'm unsure what area of math this relates to most.

Comment: In the words of cartoonist Zach Weinersmith: "Did you know that you can triple anything by multiplying it by a mathematical constant named $3$?"

Comment: If you search for the Riemann zeta function, you will problaby find the constant $-\frac{1}{12}$. Another interesting one in number theory may be Skewes`s number.

Comment: @jojobo -1/12! Pretty good I'd say

Comment: You should add $0$ to your list

Comment: @MarkBennet another good one!

Comment: Do the orders of the sporadic groups count? I don't know if group theorists would treat them as such.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/32967/27465, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2081138/96384.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are whole sequences of important rational numbers. See [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Integer_sequences) [pages](https://oeis.org/wiki/Category:Integer_sequences) on "integer" sequences (although they may have some non-integer rational values, e.g. the earliest Bernoulli numbers, which are [the basis](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/) for results such as the famous $-\tfrac{1}{12}$ result @jojobo mentioned) & [this](https://oeis.org/wiki/Category:Rational_sequences) page for rational ones.

Then there are quantities of the form $\zeta(2n)/\pi^{2n}$ with $n$ a positive integer.

One could argue every rational $s$ is important for a suitably chosen complex analysis problem due to factors of $e^{2\pi is}$ or $(1-e^{2\pi is})^{\pm1}$.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant), Legendre's constant was first conjectured to be $1.08366...$ but later proved to be exactly $1$.